# file not found #import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to integrate MapBox-GL into a react native project.
The problem is that when I run react-native run-ios --device the build fails with the error:

```
AppDelegate.m:12:9: fatal error: 'React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h' file not found
   #import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
```

But when I run the same project on an emulator, all works fine.
Anyone else has experience with this? A simple Google on this is not giving the specific result.

```
    "react": "^15.4.2",
    "react-native": "^0.39.2",
    "react-native-mapbox-gl": "^5.1.0"
```

I edited the build scheme to include React but nothing helps...

Comment: I believe the issue is that in RN 0.40 the imports have breaking changes for ios. If you can upgrade to 0.40 it should solve the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do the following: 
XCode Product ⇒ Scheme ⇒ Manage Schemes ⇒ Click '+' 
At the Target Dropdown choose "React" and after saving this, scroll down and check the *shared* checkbox

[image]